# How to get tile from tile array in world position(Pathfinding?)

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, grid, tiles

I found such a solution many developers in different places, everywhere they have a different approach, I tried to recreate their solution, but it does not work correctly.
Solution =>

```
Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100f, Color.red, 5f);
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    var result = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, 100f);
    if (result)
    {
        Debug.Log(ray);
        float percentegeX = (result.point.x + width / 2) / width;
        float percentegeY = (result.point.y + height / 2) / height;

        percentegeX = Mathf.Clamp01(percentegeX);
        percentegeY = Mathf.Clamp01(percentegeY);

         x = Mathf.RoundToInt((countX - 1) * percentegeX);
         y = Mathf.RoundToInt((countY - 1) * percentegeY);
        return board[x, y];
```

this code is Sebastyan Lague and it work good with equal rectangles. but i have this =>

```
board = new GameTileContent[countX, countY];
    
    cellWidth = 3;
    cellHeight = 4;
    width = cellWidth * countX + (spacing.x * countX);
    height = cellHeight * countY + (spacing.y * countY);

    leftEdge = transform.position - Vector3.right * width / 2 - Vector3.up * height / 2;

    for (int x = 0; x < countX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < countY; y++)
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3((x * cellWidth + cellWidth / 2f) + leftEdge.x + (x * (spacing.x * countX)),
                (y * cellHeight + cellHeight / 2f) + leftEdge.y + (y * (spacing.y * countY)), 1f);

            var obj = Instantiate(prefabTile, transform);

            board[x, y] = obj;

            obj.x = x;
            obj.y = y;
            obj.type = GameTileContent.EType.EMPTY;

            obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(cellWidth, cellHeight);
            obj.transform.position = position;
            obj.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        }
    }
```

i have cellWidth 3 and cellHeight 4 how to callculate correct way from grid tiles? i may use only raycast but it is not faster right?
and what happens in this case? Apparently, the rounding is incorrect, when I click on the edge of a tile of 2: 0 and get the data 1.94 and 0.66, then it rounds up to 2.1 tiles. If I manually set the conditions for rounding, then it’s more or less correct, but is this the wrong approach?
if this important link to vids https://youtu.be/nhiFx28e7JY?t=1197 with timeline

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mouse/touch click position to calculate the world position of the touch and then use [WorldToCell](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html) method on your tilemap to get the tile coordinates.

```
var pointerPosition = Input.mousePosition;
pointerPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pointerPosition);
pointerPosition.z = 0;
var gridPosition = groundTileMap.WorldToCell(pointerPosition);
if (!groundTileMap.HasTile(gridPosition))
{
    Debug.LogError($"{TAG} No tile");
    return;
}
```

Comment: i am not use Grid i simulate own. i hope will found good math for solve this if this way exists

Comment: @Novichok2021, why don't you use Unity's Tilemap?